# UpsetR: manually order set intersections to align multiple upset plots

Tags: r

I am making multiple upset plots using the UpsetR package and will combine them using `grid.arrange` to make a single figure.  Is it possible to coerce the order of the intersections so that they are identical between plots?

By default, it orders the bars by frequency, but you can also specify `order.by = “degree”` to order bars by number of intersecting sets. However, it does not always put bars of equivalent degree in the same order, and I have not found how to manually specify the intersection order when assigning the plot as an object and looking through the list of features. Below is an example.

```
listInput1 <- list(one = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13), 
                  two = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10), 
                  three = c(1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13),
                  four = c(1, 11, 14))
listInput2 <- list(one = c(1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13), 
                   two = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 13, 14), 
                   three = c(1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13),
                   four = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
listInput3 <- list(one = c(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13), 
                   two = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 13, 14), 
                   three = c(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14),
                   four = c(2, 6, 9, 11, 12))
listInput4 <- list(one = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17), 
                   two = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 13, 14), 
                   three = c(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14),
                   four = c(4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12))

plot.ls <- list(
  p1 = upset(fromList(listInput1), order.by = "degree", sets = c("four", "three", "two", "one"), keep.order = TRUE, empty.intersections = "on"),
  p2 = upset(fromList(listInput2), order.by = "degree", sets = c("four", "three", "two", "one"), keep.order = TRUE, empty.intersections = "on"),
  p3 = upset(fromList(listInput3), order.by = "degree", sets = c("four", "three", "two", "one"), keep.order = TRUE, empty.intersections = "on"),
  p4 = upset(fromList(listInput4), order.by = "degree", sets = c("four", "three", "two", "one"), keep.order = TRUE, empty.intersections = "on")
  )
for (v in names(plot.ls)) {
  print(plot.ls[[v]])
  grid.text(v, x = 0.65, y=0.97, gp = gpar(fontsize = 20))
  grid.edit('arrange', name = v)
  vp <- grid.grab()
  plot.ls[[v]] <- vp
}
grid.arrange(grobs = plot.ls, ncol = 2)
```

Ideally, I would have the set intersections in the following order for all plots: one&two, one, two, one&three, one&four, one&two&three, one&two&four, one&two&three&four, two&three&four, one&three&four, two&three, two&four, four, three, three&four.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem! I think the easiest solution would something like this (i.e., specify `intersections` order instead `sets` one... a bit more tedious, but it works):

```
plot.ls <- list(
  p1 = upset(fromList(listInput1), order.by = "degree", keep.order = TRUE, empty.intersections = "on", 
             intersections = list(list("one", "two"), list("one"), list("two"), list("one", "three"), list("one", "four"), list("one", "two", "three"), list("one", "two", "four"), list("one", "two", "three", "four"), list("two", "three", "four"), list("one", "three", "four"), list("two", "three"), list("two", "four"), list("four"), list("three"), list("three", "four"))),
  p2 = upset(fromList(listInput2), order.by = "degree", keep.order = TRUE, empty.intersections = "on",
             intersections = list(list("one", "two"), list("one"), list("two"), list("one", "three"), list("one", "four"), list("one", "two", "three"), list("one", "two", "four"), list("one", "two", "three", "four"), list("two", "three", "four"), list("one", "three", "four"), list("two", "three"), list("two", "four"), list("four"), list("three"), list("three", "four"))),
  p3 = upset(fromList(listInput3), order.by = "degree", keep.order = TRUE, empty.intersections = "on", 
             intersections = list(list("one", "two"), list("one"), list("two"), list("one", "three"), list("one", "four"), list("one", "two", "three"), list("one", "two", "four"), list("one", "two", "three", "four"), list("two", "three", "four"), list("one", "three", "four"), list("two", "three"), list("two", "four"), list("four"), list("three"), list("three", "four"))),
  p4 = upset(fromList(listInput4), order.by = "degree", keep.order = TRUE, empty.intersections = "on",
             intersections = list(list("one", "two"), list("one"), list("two"), list("one", "three"), list("one", "four"), list("one", "two", "three"), list("one", "two", "four"), list("one", "two", "three", "four"), list("two", "three", "four"), list("one", "three", "four"), list("two", "three"), list("two", "four"), list("four"), list("three"), list("three", "four")))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jgarces!  This approach did not work with my real data at first.  I got the following error:  Error in `[.data.frame`(data, keep) : undefined columns selected
However, my set names have spaces in them for aesthetics, so if I remove the spaces, then this works.  I have not yet figured out how to specify the intersections with set names that contain spaces.

Comment: Hi @jjcampo, I usually try to avoid working with white spaces in R because everything usually crashes downstream... Something using back ticks (`) is a possible solution, but I didn't get anything clear in your specific case. Two options: rename colnames to syntactic-correct names in R (and rename them again manually after plotting) or modify the function code (good luck!). So, sorry for not being able to help you more in detail.